# how to simply manipulate DOM from firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

There is a website, where I would like that in two specific select fields another option is SELECTED. I can change this very easily using the F12 Firefox Developer console, but how can I automatize this? So everytime when I visit the website, I would like to have this changed.

I know there is plugins like greasemonkey, but this seems to e a very big gun for a very small need. Is there another way with firefox build in tools? Or could I somehow very easily write my own plugin only for this case?

Comment: The actual greasemonkey _plugin_ might be "a very big gun", but to me this sounds like the exact use case a greasemonkey _script_ would be a perfect solution for.